# Return a single object jbuilder without as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have an object > @person

I want it returned like:

```
{ name: blah,
  anotherattribute: null,
  attribute1: false,
}
```

in the view file, I've tried json.person @person but it returns:

```
{
 person: {
    name: blah,
    anotherattribute: null,
    attribute1: false,
 }
}
```

I've tried with extract! but it skips some attributes that are part of person through inheritance so do not show up. I also cannot do one attribute at a time, there are too many. I've merge! but that does the same thing. The only way it works is if I use as_json but I prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try rendering JSON directly from the controller (without using view file):

```
render json: @person
```

This should remove `person` from the JSON response.

Comment: yes, that's how I have it working - however I would like to use jbuilder